# wso2 bps3.5.1 bpmn the comments cannot support Chinese character

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

BPS3.5.1 is running on windows. The database is mysql-5.7.13.  Mysql is configured by using utf-8.

when posting a comments via result api, the incorrect character is stored in database.

https://192.168.111.94:9443/bpmn/runtime/tasks/7525/comments
{
  "message" : "This is a 测试.",
  "saveProcessInstanceId" : true
}

I have configured bps to support utf-8  by setting 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=utf8

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a mysql encoding problem for UTF-8. It is recommended to use latin1 charset for windows. Refer point 5 in [1] of the WSO2 BPS documentation.

[1]- https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/Setting+up+MySQL